# Can I use the same USB-C port for power delivery and video at the same time?

Tags: usb, usb-3, displayport, docking-station, usb-power-delivery

I've recently bought an LG 17Z90P-K.AA78A1 laptop. According to the spec it has "USB 4 Gen3x2 Type C (x2, with Power Delivery, Display Port, Thunderbolt 4)"

I've been ploughing through the minefield of competing USB-C modes and specifications, and just getting bamboozled by all the terminology.

What I want is to have a docking station that connects to the laptop, the mains electricity supply, and my 4k monitor, so that I only need to plug in a single cable from the docking station into the laptop and it will do **both power delivery and video output** (plus all the other docking station functions) **along the same cable at the same time**.

Is this how USB-C works? and if so, are there any specific buzzwords I need to look out for on the docking station

Answer (score 3):

"Is this how USB-C works?"
Short answer - Yes.

I am currently doing **exactly** that with a Lenovo USB-C dock and an HP laptop.

I get home and plug 1 USB-C cable into my laptop, and the mouse, keyboard, webcam and monitor all get connected at the same time, as well as charging the laptop. This has the added benefit of allowing me to use all those devices with any other laptop, and my Samsung phone to enable DeX.